# Rendering problem no Android Studio 1.5

Tags: android, android-studio

Olá, pessoal.
Como resolver o problema *rendering problem* no Android Studio 1.5?

Estou a vários dias tentando e nada de conseguir, já que fiquei sabendo que há vários fatores que fazem ocorrer esse problema.

Normalmente eu abria o projeto e aparecia uma tela com a pré-visualização do aplicativo, mas de repente parou!

Estarei deixando uma imagem que descreve melhor a situação.
Desde já agradeço a todos!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso acontece bastante, quando sai alguma atualização, geralmente não funciona mais. já atualizou a versao?

Comment: Sim, a versão atual do Android Studio é a 1.5.

Comment: tente usar a versao 23 no lugar da 16

Comment: mantenha o SDK atualizado, e se você precisa usar a versão 16 coloque ela como mínima, não como a se usar, deixe a mais atual disponível para padrão.